# Reverse Engineering Reports

Tags: c#, sql-server, reverse-engineering

I am trying to reverse engineer some reports from an existing system.

The situation is that I have re-created the database locally to me.  I dont have any of the original front end code.  I need to create the code for reports that the existing system does so that I can add extra functionality the client requires.

Right now its a bit of a tangled mess as I try and work out what all the tables do and mean (there is like 50 tables and only 1 has a foreign key so its a bit confusing).

The client has the existing system up and running on his server, just with no access to the code.

Is there something we can do to see the actual queries that are being run by the software?

i.e.

1) run report on old system

2) get a log from SQL server 2000 of all queries made

I think this would save me a crapload of time and give more accurate results but i cant figure out how to do this.

Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You can run the SQL Server Profiler. It allows you to watch the execution of commands on the server. In order to watch SQL commands its best to watch "SQL: Batch completed" events.

Comment: is this a separate download or will come with sql server 2000?

Comment: In the Management Studio have a look in the `Tools` menu.